# How can I instantiate this repository?

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0, xunit

I have this classes:

**Test.cs:**

```
public class Test
{
    private readonly Mock<Repository> _repository;

    public Test()
    {
        this._repository = new Mock<Repository>();
    }

    [Fact]
    public async void Test1()
    {
        this._repository.Setup(x => x.Rep.GetAllAsync()) 
            .ReturnsAsync(Fix.GetMock());

        controller sut = new controller();
        ActionResult result = await sut.GetAll();
        OkObjectResult objectResults = (OkObjectResult) result;
        objectResults?.Value.Should().BeOfType<Entity[]>();
    }
}
```

**Controller.cs:**

```
public class Controller : BaseApiController
{
    private readonly IRepository _repository;

    [HttpGet]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    public async Task<ActionResult> GetAll()
    {
        IEnumerable<Rep> rep = await _repository.Rep.GetAllAsync();
        return Ok(rep);
    }
}
```

**Repository:**

```
public class Repository : IRepository
{
    private readonly Context _context;

    public Repository(Context context)
    {
        this._context = context;
    }

    public ValueTask<IEnumerable<Rep>> GetAllAsync(Rep rep)
    {
        return this._context.Set<Rep>().ToArrayAsync();
    }
}
```

My doubt is: How can I use **Repository** in the **Test/Controller** class, instantiating it, without passing the **Context** via DI in the **Test/Controller** constructor?

Comment: You are saying you cannot change Test Class? If not then how will you use the repository in Test class?

Comment: @AjayManagaon, you are right, I will remove this observation, thanks for point it.

Comment: You should replace the `async void` in your code with `async Task`. You should almost never do `async void`. Make sure you read [Async Await Best Practices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#avoid-async-void). It's essential reading for any modern .NET developer.

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to use DI to instantiate your repository class in your app, and let it create your controller too?